# Video player control button

Tags: video, controls

for below codes, was able to run the video and it can be controlled with the play and pause button.

However, when it is placed within td tag in a table, the video can no longer be controlled with those buttons.

Probably missing something. Pls help.

```
<p>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="219" HEIGHT="171" id="movie" ALIGN>
  <param NAME="movie" value="video.swf">
  <param NAME="quality" value="High">
  <param NAME="bgcolor" value="FFFFFF">
  <param name="_cx" value="5794">
  <param name="_cy" value="4524">
  <param name="FlashVars" value="-1">
  <param name="Src" value="video.swf">
  <param name="WMode" value="Window">
  <param name="Play" value="-1">
  <param name="Loop" value="0">
  <param name="SAlign" value>
  <param name="Menu" value="-1">
  <param name="Base" value>
  <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
  <param name="Scale" value="ShowAll">
  <param name="DeviceFont" value="0">
  <param name="EmbedMovie" value="0">
  <param name="SWRemote" value>
  <EMBED src="video.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF  WIDTH="246" HEIGHT="187" NAME="movie" ALIGN=""  TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED>
</object>
</p>
<p><a href="javascript:document.movie.Play()"><font face="Arial">&#9658;</font>play&nbsp; </a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <font face="Arial">
<a href="javascript:document.movie.StopPlay()">&#9553;pause</a></font></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

[I am not allowed to write comments] 
Could you please provide a minimal working example. Also the framework/plugin you are working with should be mentioned (where comes the video.swf from?). The code above can not be used. Further more, why do you try to use a flash video since HTML5 has better support?